# If I change maintainer info in a deb I create, what will be effected?

Tags: rpm, apt, rpmbuild, deb

I have some software which I distribute in .deb and .rpm formats.

If I change the Vendor or Homepage information in the package:

- Will anything break on future upgrades?
- Would anyone even know unless they typed `apt-cache show [packagename]`?

Another way to ask this might be:

- What shouldn't be changed in a package's meta information, because it might cause problems down the line?

Answer (score 1):

For RPM, the metadata for vendor/URL (and packager/distribution) is mostly informative. There are some distribution level tools that do some simple sanity checks (like vendor/URL exists), but those tools are usually used only for doing QA on release assemblies, likely not you as a packager.